# Programatically register an App on Azure AD

Tags: asp.net, azure, office365, adal, outlook-restapi

I am building a website (ASP.net MVC) that integrates with Office 365. The basic idea is that the website should be able to add items into the users' calendar, tasks, and store document into a sharepoint site.

Where I am currently stuck is in order for my website to perform these operations it needs to be registered on the users' Azure AD as an app.
Is there a way to programatically register the website as an app during the user registration process on my site?

Are there any other tips on how i can go about this?

Comment: Have you considered making your app multi-tenant?  Have you taken a look at this sample?  https://github.com/AzureADSamples/WebApp-MultiTenant-OpenIdConnect-DotNet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The app does not have to be registered in the user's Azure AD. You would want to register it in your Azure AD and mark it multi-tenant as Rich suggested. That would allow users from other Office 365 organizations to sign in to your app.